# Hide output from expect

Tags: linux, expect

Here's part of an expect script

```
#/usr/bin/expect 

spawn -noecho kwalletcli -f Passwords -e keyofmypassword
expect ".*"
set passwd $expect_out(buffer)

# do some thing
# ...
```

It read password from kwalletcli, and store in variable `passwd`. So I can connect to the servers with this `passwd`.

However, the output of kwalletcli is pass through expect and show on console. How can I hide that.

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681928/how-can-i-make-an-expect-script-prompt-for-a-password  BTW this 夜弓 not that *叶公* :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try adding

```
log_user 0
```

to your script. That should turn off the display to stdout.

If you want to turn it on again for the "do some thing" part of the program, re-enable it

```
log_user 1
```

Answer (score 1):

using this command:

```
exec >log 2>&1
```

you can forward your output to a file or you can pass it to dev/null

Answer (score 0):

is with -stty and stty

stty -echo
send_user "Password: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set password $expect_out(1,string)
stty echo

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.