# bash script - use expect without plot command to screen

Tags: linux, bash, expect

i'm new with expect.
i wanted to ask how can i execute a command but without plot to the screen
the command itself.

**for example:**

```
expect "*?>"
send "echo done"
expect "*?>"
```

without plotting to the screen "echo done" but ONLY "done".

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601526/hide-output-from-expect if that can help you.

Comment: no good since it hide all the output from screen
i want to hide ONLY the command and not the command's output

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if {[info exists tty_spawn_id]} {
    stty -echo
}

log_user 0

...

send_user "done"
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't ketch ya.
can you please explain?