# Trying to use expect in Mac script

Tags: bash, macos

Trying to write a simple shell script to ssh into a server and then run a tail for error logs, but I'm getting an error saying "spawn command not found". I'm using expect rather than bash and have checked /usr/bin and it is there. Script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
echo "starting tail"
echo "password for the box?"
read -s theBoxPassword
spawn ssh root@10.0.0.10
expect "root@10.0.0.10's password: "
send $theBoxPassword\r
```

Not exactly sure what the problem is. I've looked at a bunch of examples online and it seems like I have the shebang thing right and the syntax correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be mixing shell (`/bin/sh`) syntax with `expect` syntax.  Both `echo` and `read` are shell commands.  Expect performs input and output using commands like `expect_user` and `send_user`, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/683386/147356).

If you want to mix shell syntax and expect, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "starting tail"
echo "password for the box?"
read -s theBoxPassword

expect <<EOF
spawn ssh root@10.0.0.10
expect "root@10.0.0.10's password: "
send "$theBoxPassword\r"
EOF
```

This uses the shell to produce your prompt and read the password, and then passes a script to expect on stdin.  The shell will perform variable substitution on the script before it gets passed to expect.

Comment: Would #!/bin/bash work at the top (I have another script that I could add this to in order to keep things all in one file)?

Comment: Seems to work, but rather than showing the prompt for the box that I ssh into, I get kicked back out to my computer's command prompt. Did I miss something else in the script?

Comment: Your script is currently working as expected. Add the expect command `communicate` just before the `EOF` line to get what it sounds like you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Ended up getting it working by adding expect "theBox:~#" then send "tail stuff" then expect "$ ". Showed the tail and I was able to ctrl-C out cleanly.