# Can expect scripts read data from stdin?

Tags: bash, expect

When executing `expect` scripts, arguments are visible on `ps ax` which can be a security vulnerability if they are sensitive.

Trying to automate opening a tab on iTerm2, running `ssh admin@host` and entering the passphrase when asked `Enter passphrase for key '/Users/admin/.ssh/key'` (the key is encrypted using that passphrase).

```
Host host
HostName 1.2.3.4
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key
```

I would like to supply the passphrase to bash using `read -sp 'Passphrase: ' passphrase` and then pipe it to `expect` (which isn’t perfect at all from an OPSEC perspective but much better than having the passphrase leaked on `ps ax`).

Perhaps there is a better way?

Bellow is some code that works but leaks the passphrase on `ps ax`. Commented out is what I wish was possible (piping the passphrase to `expect`).

## batch.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function new_tab() {
  command=${1//\"/\\\"}
  osascript \
    -e "tell application \"iTerm2\"" \
    -e "tell current window" \
    -e "create tab with default profile" \
    -e "delay 1" \
    -e "tell current session" \
    -e "write text \"$command\"" \
    -e "end tell" \
    -e "end tell" \
    -e "end tell" > /dev/null
}

hostnames=(
  "hostname-1"
  "hostname-2"
)

read -sp 'Passphrase: ' passphrase

for hostname in "${hostnames[@]}"; do
  # new_tab "echo $passphrase | expect $(pwd)/expect.exp \"$hostname\""
  new_tab "expect $(pwd)/expect.exp \"$hostname\" \"$passphrase\""
done
```

## expect.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set hostname [lindex $argv 0]
set passphrase [lindex $argv 1]

spawn ssh admin@$hostname
expect "passphrase"
send "$passphrase\r"
interact
```

Comment: Do it in expect, that way you don't even need to pass the data to the child process: https://stackoverflow.com/q/681928/7552

Comment: Hey @glennjackman. Thanks for the feedback. Trying to avoid hard coding the passphrase or leaking it on `ps ax`. I would like to enter the passphrase when needed while making it "amnesic" as the passphrase itself is encrypted in a password manager. As I’m looping through hosts in bash to run `expect` in individual tabs, I believe I have to prompt for the passphrase in bash.

Comment: In general you could just pass the username and password to your expect script on `stdin`, but since you're launching the script via `osascript` in a new terminal tab, `stdin` isn't going to be connected to anything useful. You could write the credentials to a file and then read that in your expect script.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for your feedback. How do you read from stdin in `expect`? Btw, I’m open to feedback on how to achieve the end goal vs trying to make the above code work.

Comment: Expect scripts are written in the [tcl](https://www.tcl.tk/) language, so something like https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/How+do+I+read+and+write+files+in+Tcl is a good starting point.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: @larsks `set passphrase [gets stdin]` is what I am looking for, but the `expect` script exits at eof. Do you know how to prevent that? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842683/how-can-i-prevent-expect-from-exiting-at-eof-when-reading-data-from-stdin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `expect` can read from `stdin` but there is a caveat: reading from `stdin` isn’t compatible with `interact`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57847199/4579271

## Reading a single variable

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set passphrase [gets stdin]
```

## Reading multiple variables

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set data [gets stdin]
scan $data "%s %s" hostname passphrase
```

Another approach is to use environment variables (as suggested by Glenn) but there is another caveat: environment variables are only available to the shell in which they are defined and its children.

Environment variables defined in `batch.sh` would therefore not be available in the iTerm2 tabs created using `osascript`.

So the only secure option I have is to drop `osascript` altogether and have all the code (`batch.sh` and `expect.exp`) execute in the same shell and use environment variables to pass variables between `bash` and `expect`.

## batch.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

hostnames=(
  "hostname-1"
  "hostname-2"
)

read -sp 'SSH key passphrase: ' passphrase

echo ""

export PASSPHRASE=$passphrase

for hostname in "${hostnames[@]}"; do
  export HOSTNAME=$hostname
  expect "$(dirname "$0")/expect.exp"
done
```

## expect.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 10

spawn ssh admin@$env(HOSTNAME)

expect {
  default {
    puts "\nCould not connect to $env(HOSTNAME)"
    exit 1
  }
  "passphrase" {
    send "$env(PASSPHRASE)\r"
  }
}

expect {
  default {
    puts "\nWrong passphrase"
    exit 1
  }
  "admin@$env(HOSTNAME)" {
    # Add automation commands here, then exit SSH session to close expect script moving on to the next hostname
    send "exit\r"
  }
}

interact
```

Answer (score 3):

In the bashscript, read the password and then `export` the variable. In expect, access it from the environment with `$env(passphrase)`

Comment: Thanks Glenn. Trying to avoid leaking the passphrase to the environment (which other scripts can read right?) or `ps ax` hence trying to find how to read from stdin in `expect`. Does this make any sense (I’m a an `expect` newbie).

Comment: Only programs you launch from that shell script can see that environment variable.

Comment: Does this approach work between tabs? Getting `no such variable` in the other tabs.

Comment: It looks like this approach will _not_ work the way you're mixing shell, applescript and expect

Comment: @glennjackman , *"Only programs you launch from that shell script can see that environment variable."* -- this is not true. for example on linux you can see a process' env vars by `cat /proc/<PID>/environ`.