# How can I wrap an interactive program into non-interactive which works with pipes?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, expect

To avoid the XY-problem issue:

X problem: given an interactive TUI program, how can I wrap it into a non-interactive one (a batch script which accepts some inputs in specific format from stdin and output to stdout in specific format) in a suggested way.

Y problem: I'm trying to use `expect` to wrap [`passphrase2pgp`](https://github.com/skeeto/passphrase2pgp) into a batch script, but met some trouble when dealing with STDIN & STDOUT with pipe.

(PS: I prefer some advice for this kind of problems than a workaround of specific example, since it's not a complicated job, I think there must be some simple and direct way to achieve it, no tricks and workaround. But I'm not sure whether the implementation details of the be wrapped programs will make things very different, anyway, pointing this out -- if it is the fact -- will also be very helpful)

Suppose I want to wrap some interactive program (e.g. `passphrase2pgp`, or `ssh-keygen` which is more well-known) into an non-interactive script named `my-keygen`, so that I can use it like

```
printf pwd | my-keygen | gpg --import
```

In this case, `my-keygen` is expected to receive password from piped STDIN, and output the private key to STDOUT, which will be piped to `gpg --import`.

But use `passphrase2pgp` directly like `printf pwd | passphrase2pgp --uid alice --repeat 0 | gpg --import` doesn't work at all, since it will **still prompt for the passphrase interactivly**.

This brings me to use `expect`, following is `my-keygen` using `expect`:

(if you have `nix` installed, change "expect" in shebang to "nix-shell" so you can run it directly without install `passphrase2pgp`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
#! nix-shell -p passphrase2pgp -p expect -i expect

spawn passphrase2pgp --uid alice --repeat 0 --armor

expect "passphrase:"

interact
```

But this script still doesn't work, when used like `printf pwd | my-keygen`, it **exit too early** without printing anything out.

And I find it works when I answer questions from tty, it just does not work if the STDIN is from pipe.

I searched a lot and found something useful:

- [How to send standard input through a pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312743/)
- [Can expect scripts read data from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837869/can-expect-scripts-read-data-from-stdin)
- [How can I pipe initial input into process which will then be interactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843741/how-can-i-pipe-initial-input-into-process-which-will-then-be-interactive)

which let me know that there is an `EOF` in the piped content which will cause the interactive program exit without finishing its job.

A minimal example to reproduce what happened is:

1. create a file named `test` with following content

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env expect

   spawn bash

   interact
   ```
2. run `chmod +x ./test` to make it executable
3. run `echo 'echo hello' | ./test` and confirm that `hello` is not printed as expected
4. run `echo 'echo hello' | bash` and confirm that `hello` is printed as expected this way

So is there any solution to make `my-keygen` work as expected? And to be more general, what is the suggested way to such a thing?

---

(edited 2022/10/11)

The *exit too early* issue of the `expect` version is fixed (thanks to many helpful answers):
just read lines in a while loop and send them one-by-one, and NOT use the `interact` command of `expect` at the end of the script.

But in this way, the output of the spawned process is not printed to stdout, if we need to pipe its STDOUT to another program, like `gpg --import`, then we **need to control the STDOUT** of `my-keygen` to only print the armored key, and no extra stuff. It will be better if your solution shows how to achieve that.

(I already received some suggestion that `expect` is not a good choice for this purpose - thanks @pynexj - so feel free to post your answer if you have better solution which is not based on `expect`.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248825/discussion-on-question-by-luochen1990-how-can-i-wrap-an-interactive-program-into).

Answer (score 2):

Use `while read` construction like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r input; do
     opts+=("$input")
done

echo "${opts[@]}"
```

Testing:

```
$ echo -e "myinfo1\nmyinfo2\nmysecret3" | ./test
myinfo1 myinfo2 mysecret3
```

Using with ssh-keygen:

```
$ ssh-keygen --help
unknown option -- -
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile] [-m format]
                  [-t dsa | ecdsa | ecdsa-sk | ed25519 | ed25519-sk | rsa]
                  [-N new_passphrase] [-O option] [-w provider]
       ssh-keygen -p [-f keyfile] [-m format] [-N new_passphrase
...

ssh-keygen -p -f "${opts[0]}" -m "${opts[1]}" -N "${opts[2]}"
```

Comment: So how can we wrap an interactive program into non-interactive with this idea ?

Comment: What if the wrapped program (`ssh-keygen` here) doesn't support CLI arguments and have to be used interactivly ?

Comment: ummm,  `ssh-keygen` is indeed a bad example,  actually I'm trying to wrap `passphrase2pgp`, I use `ssh-keygen` as example here because it is more well known.

Comment: Well, this `while read` method could be paired with expect than.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're echoing your string, the newlines are being sent as literal characters and not being interpreted as newlines so there is only one line of stdin being passed to expect that gets completely consumed the first time you read stdin. There are a couple ways to fix this:

1. Use `echo -e`

```
echo -e "myinfo1\nmyinfo2\nmysecret3" | my-keygen
```

2. [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

```
echo "myinfo1"$'\n'"myinfo2"$'\n'"mysecret3" | my-keygen
```

3. Using actual newlines

```
echo "myinfo1
myinfo2
mysecret3" | my-keygen
```

4. A here-document

```
my-keygen <<EOF
myinfo1
myinfo2
mysecret3
EOF
```

Comment: I added a minimal example to reproduce and explain what happend to my script, could you please have a try?

Comment: You are presenting `echo -e` as the first option where really it should be the absolutely last one for completeness' sake if at all; and then you should definitely include `printf`, which is the proper solution to problems where maybe you would have considered `echo -e`

Comment: @tripleee Could you have a try about `echo abc | passphrase2pgp --uid bob` or `echo -e abc | passphrase2pgp --uid bob` ?  it just doesn't work.

Comment: Now I find out that the problem is about `EOF` causing `interact` exit.  And thank you for pointing out the `EOL` issue of `echo`, but it seems not the key of the problem I met here